# What is the typescript type of dayjs object

Tags: reactjs, typescript, datepicker, antd, dayjs

I am using the ant-design date picker component with dayjs as the date library.

The component is controlled with the initial value being `null` and the value changes to dayjs object based on some operations in the code.

The below code is a part of the implementation.

```
function Demo() {
  const [now, setNow] = useState<any>(null);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{JSON.stringify(now)}</p>
      <button onClick={() => setNow(dayjs())}>Update Time</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Currently, I am using `any` as the type for now which has to be replaced by a valid type.

I tried the type to be `null | typeof dayjs()`

But this didn't work.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### import { Dayjs } from "dayjs"

> Day.js ships with official type declarations for TypeScript in NPM package out of the box.

`Dayjs` is the required type of dayjs() object.

Update these two lines in your code.

```
import dayjs, { Dayjs } from "dayjs";

const [now, setNow] = useState<Dayjs | null>(null);
```

Check this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dayjs-typescript-92bflh?file=/src/App.tsx) for a working code snippet.